# C# code to Powershell - object instantiation using new object<x>(y)

Tags: c#, powershell, apache-kafka

I have the below piece of C# code I'm trying to convert to Powershell.

```
using (var consumer = new Consumer<Ignore, string>(config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8))
```

How can I handle the <>()-part in the object instantiation?

Answer (score 2):

Generic type signatures in PowerShell are easy - just replace `<>` with `[]`:

```
$deserializer = [Namespace.StringDeserializer]::new([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$Consumer = [Namespace.Consumer[Namespace.Ignore,string]]::new($config, $null, $deserializer)
```

(Replace `Namespace` with the actual namespace containing the `Consumer`, `Ignore` and `StringDeserializer` types)

Comment: Ah this is called "generic type signatures" - thanks for that. I tried to search for "<>" characters but that was quiet too generic and returned all kind of results.

Comment: This might be a little off-topic, but what does the `[\`\`2]` something-or-other represent in the signature?  I've never had a need to use generic types as of yet, but I've seen that in some code examples.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 \`2 just means the generic type has 2 type parameters (`List[string]` will show `1 for example)